# Chrome DevTools extension loads twice when opened in different tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension in DevTools. It works great unless I open it in another tab. When it is opened in another tab it loads my inserted-script.js file for each instance that the DevTools extension is open. What might be causing this? I'm happy to share what I can, but I'm unsure where to start.

Edit: Here's the manifest.json file:

```
{
    "name": "My DevTools Thing",
    "version": "0.5",
    "description": "Hello.",
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "js/background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "js/content.js"
    ],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Edit 2: To add some further context - let's say I have devTools open on tab 1 and all it does it display "Hello!". The first time it's open it displays once.

I then open a new tab, open devTools, then my extension, it shows:

"Hello!"

"Hello!"

On my original tab it has now appended:

"Hello!" (the original)

"Hello!" (from the new tab)

"Hello!" (from the new tab)

If I open a THIRD tab and open the extension...

"Hello!" x 3 (new tab)

The other tabs will have the 3 "Hello!"s from the original appended to it.

Comment: You'll have to show your code before someone can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can control your content script execution using manifest file of your extension, prevent your content script from loading into Iframe or a specific set of urls. Here's an example of manifest file:

```
"all_frames": true,
"js": [ "ContentOnDocStart.js" ],
"matches": [ "http:///", "https:///" ],
"exclude_matches": [ ],
"run_at": "document_start"
```

Also, include '*chrome.tabs.onUpdate.addListener*' fire each tabs [state  changes](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated).